# JS callback on asp button

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Um, I have this guy:

`<div class="buttonRight"><asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" Width="68px"/></div>`

which renders out to

`<div class="buttonRight">
<input type="submit" name="_$_$pc$pc$tabTO$_$uc0$popupSelectCompetition$btnOK" value="OK" id="____pc_pc_tabTO___uc0_popupSelectCompetition_btnOK" style="width:68px;" /></div>`

I need to call some javascript on that button without altering its behavior otherwise.  I tried putting an OnClick asp attribute but that seems to be for postbacks to call server code,  not passing through a javascript hook to the rendered html.

I also don't understand how the `input` being `type='submit'` affects me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your client-side code to the **OnClientClick** property :

```
<div class="buttonRight">
    <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" Width="68px" 
       OnClientClick="alert('client side scripts here');"/>
</div>
```

OnClick property used for server side events.

Or add onclick attribute to your control like that at code behind :

```
btnOK.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('client side scripts here');");
```